# What is an easy to use, standard input method for writing Korean on a Macbook?

Tags: hangul

I am a total beginner for Korean and want to take notes for the vowels and consonnes I am learning like "eu" and "eo", or "k".  What is a standard and convenient input method on a Macbook ? Below are the  input  methods I can use from my Mac.

[image: Input methods for Korean]

Answer (score 1):

We commonly use 2-Set Korean layout(dubeolsik, 두벌식, KS X 5002) on the QWERTY layout. Of course you can choose 3-Set Korean layout(sebeolsik, 세벌식), but There might be less informations about that.

Maybe this Apple support document might help you.
https://support.apple.com/guide/korean-input-method/korean-hangul-input-method-user-guide-him001/mac

Comment: If the OP plans to type Hangul in other OS's (windows, android, ios, etc), probably 두벌식 is THE standard layout.

Comment: @krim is right. In fact, 3-Set Korean Keyboard layout is not a standard. But, Korean stenographer, especially those belonging to the Korean National Assembly or courts, are using it a lot thanks to its fast typing speed... So I think we might be considered it as a de-facto standard?

Comment: I agree that 세벌식 layouts are widely used and a de facto standard. I just wanted to point out that, on other platforms (especially on mobile OS's), 세벌식 layouts might not be so available as 두벌식 is. Not to mention "roman-based" layouts which are not even remotely standard-ish.

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to a QWERTY keyboard layout, then the HNC Romaja input method may be the most straightforward to use.

At any rate, the “Show Keyboard Viewer” function can be helpful.